# Preserving leading zeros in Blade view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am writing a Laravel 7 application using Blade views. One of my MySQL tables contains the clients `tools` which have an `id` that follows no specific pattern (restructuring these ids is out of discussion since they come from another system the client will not change). Some of these ids have a leading zero which is supposed to be shown in all the views, like e.g. 055A.

The ids are stored with leading zeros in the database (varchar(64)), no issue there. But when a blade view shows the ids, the leading zero is gone and moreover, the link to `edit` and `delete` is like `myapp/public/tool/5A5/edit` which leads to an error ofc.

My approach was to show the ids with `<td>{{ sprintf('%04d', $tool->id) }}</td>` but not all ids have 4 chars and still the links are like `myapp/public/tool/5A5/edit`, because Blade takes the whole `$tool` object. Here's the section from my view:

```
@foreach($tools as $tool)
<tr>
   <td>{{ sprintf('%04d', $tool->id) }}</td> //not enough!
   <td>{{ $tool->title }}</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $tool->tooltype->name }}</td>
   @can('manage-tools', App\User::class)
   <td class="td-actions text-right">
      <form action="{{ route('tool.destroy', $tool) }}" method="post">
         @csrf  
         <a rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-success btn-link" href="{{ route('tool.edit', $tool) }}" data-original-title="" title="">
            <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
            <div class="ripple-container"></div>
         </a>
         @method('delete')
         <button type="button"  value="disabled" disabled class="btn btn-danger btn-link" data-original-title="" title="delete" 
         onclick="confirm('{{ __("Wirklich löschen?") }}') ? this.parentElement.submit() : ''">
         <i class="material-icons">close</i>
         <div class="ripple-container"></div>
         </button>
      </form>
   </td>
   @endcan
</tr>
@endforeach
```

From my ToolController:

```
public function index(Tool $model)
{
  $this->authorize('manage-tools', User::class);
  return view('tools.index',['tools' => $model->get()]); 
}
```

Comment: I added the controller function to my post and no, I don't do migrations.

Comment: when doing `return view('tools.index',['tools' => dd($model->get())]);` the zeros are preserved, `05A5` is still there.

Comment: yes and `$tool->id` is `5A5` also for `href="{{ route('tool.edit', $tool) }}"`.

Comment: No, same thing, no zeros. Is it possible that this is a PHP config issue?

Comment: Yey! That's it! Just make it an answer, so I can give you the credits. What is this option and how does it work for a varchar field when string can't be incremented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel will do some "magic" behind the scenes to handle id fields gracefully, for example stripping leading zeros. Since in most cases model ids are incrementing, it is comes with this behavior as a default. You can disable this behavior using the following setting on the Model you do not have an incrementing id field. In your case:

```
class Tool extends Model
{
    public $incrementing = false;
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note here for those who have to preserve leading zeros inside double mustaches. I am using Laravel 8 and by adding `protected $casts = ['id_column_name' => 'array']` helps me keep the blade from remove the leading zeros, therefore links to edit page work correctly.